# Pygame not drawing rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame trying to create a flappy bird.
I have written the following code so far.
https://gist.github.com/Devansha2007/fa0e5554547e6b1395e3bf3783a4c53d

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 568))
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.png')
bird = pygame.image.load('player.png')
pole_width = 70
pole_gap = 100
pole_x = 320
top_pole_height = random.randint(100, 400)
pole_color = (220, 85, 57)
bird_x = 0
bird_y = 0
score = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bird_y = bird_y + 6
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bird_y = bird_y - 6
    surface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    surface.blit(bird, (bird_x, bird_y))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, pole_color, pygame.Rect(pole_x, 0, pole_width, top_pole_height))
    # pole_x = pole_x - 500
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Please can you post your code here

Comment: You have to add the relevant code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The rectangle is out of bounds, because of `pole_x = pole_x - 500`.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle is out of bounds, because of `pole_x = pole_x - 500` and the initial x-coordinate. Remove `pole_x = pole_x - 500` and change the intilial x-coordinate:

```py
pole_x = 320 - pole_width

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bird_y = bird_y + 6
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bird_y = bird_y - 3
    surface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    surface.blit(bird, (bird_x, bird_y))
    
    # pole_x = pole_x - 500 <-- remove or change this
    
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, pole_color, pygame.Rect(pole_x, 0, pole_width, top_pole_height))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

If you want to move the rectangle slowly and smoothly, change the movement:

<s>`pole_x = pole_x - 500`</s>

```py
pole_x -= 1
```

Applicaition loop:

```py
while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bird_y = bird_y + 6
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bird_y = bird_y - 3
    surface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    surface.blit(bird, (bird_x, bird_y))
    pole_x -= 1
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, pole_color, pygame.Rect(pole_x, 0, pole_width, top_pole_height))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)`
```

Comment: I removed it and then tried again but it is still not working

Comment: @Devansha change the initialization of  _pole_x_: `pole_x = 320 - pole_width`